# Nexus Security Vulnerabilities

Tags: nexus, sonatype

We are using `Nexus version 2.11.3-01` and when scanned by the `IBM AppScan` tool, it is reporting that it has the `Cross-Site Request Forgery` vulnerability

Does anyone know if this is a known vulnerability and has this been addressed in later versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you believe you've found a vulnerability in Nexus please contact Sonatype Support with the details. We will evaluate your claim, and take appropriate action.